# Uniformly bounded sequence in $W^{2,1}_{q}(\Omega^{\prime})$ has a subsequence in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

> Let $D$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega=D\times (0,T)$. For any $q>1$ and any $\Omega^{\prime}\Subset\Omega$, $\left\|v_k\right\|_{W_{q}^{2,1}(\Omega^\prime)<+\infty}$, where $M(\Omega^\prime)$ is independent of $k$. By the embedding theorems and a diagonalization argument, there exists a subsequence of $v_k$ (still denote it by ${v_k}$) such that $v_k\to$ some $v$ in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) $ for some $0<\alpha<1$.

By the embedding theorems, if $q>n+2$, then $W_{q}^{2,1}(\Omega^{\prime})\hookrightarrow C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}(\overline{\Omega^\prime})$, where $\alpha=1-\frac{n+2}{q}$. Thus, $\left\| v_{k} \right\|_{C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}(\overline{\Omega}^{\prime})}\le M^\prime(\Omega^{\prime})$.
I don't know how to use a "diagonalization argument". In the proof of Arzelà–Ascoli, we used a diagonalization argument, but Arzelà–Ascoli is for a subset of $C(M)$, where $M$ is a compact metric space. Can we use a similar argument in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}(\overline{\Omega^\prime})$?

Comment: Could you add a little more context and details: where does this question come from? what are the exact assumptions, what exactly do you want to prove? Also there seems to be some typos. Could you correct them (e.g. the first part of your question involves mentions an $M$ but it is not used).

Comment: The question is from [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-337-02/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5.pdf), in page 558. $M(\Omega^{\prime})$ is a constant gets from $L^{p}$ interior estimate, which is depend on the measure of $\Omega^{\prime}$.

Answer (score 1):

A **diagonal argument** is a general technique when you want to make a proof which requires extracting a subsequence from a subsequence from a subsequence from ... from a sequence, a (countably) infinite number of times, in order to create a new sequence satisfying simultaneously many properties. You can use it in many contexts. It does not depend on the underlying space.

Say that you start from a sequence $(u^0_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and that you know that you can extract from it a subsequence $(u^1_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which satisfies some asymptotic property $P_1$. Now assume that you can iterate the process to extract from the sequence $(u^k_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a subsequence $(u^{k+1}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfying the asymptotic property $P_{k+1}$. Define
$$
\bar{u}_n := u^n_n 
\quad 
\text{(hence the name "diagonal")}
$$
Then the sequence $(\bar{u}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisifies **simultaneously** all the properties $P_k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

---

In the type of proof you are mentioning, the *diagonal argument* typically iterates over different (increasing) domains $\Omega'$ in order for the final sequence to have a property on the whole $\Omega$.

More precisely, take $\Omega_n$ an increasing sequence of open subsets $\Omega_n \Subset \Omega$. For each fixed $n$, applying your reasoning to $\Omega' = \Omega_n$, you know that $(v_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded in $W^{2,1}_q(\Omega_n)$, so also in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}(\overline{\Omega_n})$.

Now you start by extracting from $(v_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a subsequence $(v^1_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges towards some limit in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}(\overline{\Omega_1})$. From this subsequence, you extract one which converges on $\Omega_2$, and so on as detailed above.

In the end, you obtain convergence in $C^{1+\alpha,\frac{1+\alpha}{2}}_{loc}(\Omega)$ (by definition of the $C_{loc}$ space).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know how to get the conclusion in a subdomain of $\Omega$.

Comment: I updated the answer above.

Comment: How to get the subsequence $(v_{k}^{1})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(v_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$? Sorry for my poor English and thanks for your patience.

Comment: You have to look for a compact embedding theorem for the sapce $W^{2,1}_q$ which you are considering.

Comment: Yes! Using this theorem: Let $,$ be constants and $0≤<$. Then $C^{k,k/2}(\overline{Q}_{T})\overset{C}{\hookrightarrow}C^{l,l/2}(\overline{Q}_{T})$. One can get $W^{2,1}_{}\stackrel{}{\hookrightarrow}^{1+\beta,\frac{1+\beta}{2}}$ for $0<\beta<\alpha$.